# What are best known attacks for finding partial target pre-image?

Tags: collision-resistance, preimage-resistance

Just a follow up on this question since I don't have enough point to comment: 
[Does a partial preimage attack imply a preimage attack?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/35833/does-a-partial-preimage-attack-imply-a-preimage-attack)

*Partial target preimage attack*: Given $M$ and t-bit partial target of $d \leftarrow H(M)$, find $M^*$ such that t-bit of $d^* \leftarrow H(M^*)$ is the same as the t-bit of $d$ at the same position.

My question is what best known attacks are.

Answer (score 1):

In the generic setting, a $t$-bit partial preimage attack on an $n$-bit oracle $m \mapsto f(m)$ is the same as a full preimage attack on a $t$-bit oracle $m \mapsto \operatorname{trunc}_t(f(m))$.  If $f$ was uniformly distributed in $n$-bit functions, then $\operatorname{trunc}_t \circ f$ is uniformly distributed in $t$-bit functions, so there's no advantage to be had in knowing that it is a truncation of a larger oracle.

Of course, for *particular* functions $f$, there may be better partial preimage attacks, like $f(0^t \mathbin\| m) = 0^t \mathbin\| \operatorname{trunc}_{n - t}(H(m))$, $f(b \mathbin\| m) = H(m)$.  But we would need more particular details about $f$ like this to say.